# qt windows include boost thread header failed

Tags: c++, windows, qt, boost, qmake

I want to include boost in my qt application in windows, So:

In my .pro file, I add:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/library/boost_1_55_0
```

In main.cpp

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
```

When build, cause this error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'boost/thread/mutex.hpp'
```

I am sure the path is correct. And it is very strange.

Comment: Please show the output of the (n)make VERBOSE=1 command to see which include paths the compiler uses. Perhaps the INCLUDEPATH is overwritten somewhere else, who knows. Also, do you have a file path like `D:/library/boost_1_55_0/boost/thread/mutex.hpp`?

Comment: @LaszloPapp, thank you. I checked the compiled output. It jumps over the qmake step. So my .pro file doesn't take effect.

Comment: Have you rerun qmake explicitly? Are you using QtCreator?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Yes. I use QtCreator. When I change .pro file. The build process doesn't run qmake. When I run qmake, it's ok. But why it doesn't run qmake automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have to re-run qmake explicitly. Here you can find the corresponding long-standing issue:

[Creator should know when to rerun qmake](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-231)